# Android xml layout text visibility issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm work with android xml layout. So, I need two circle like screenshot with two textview. My text view is overlapping, and text color is wrong. Text1 good color, Text2 wrong color. How I can solve this problem ?

```
bringToFront(); and invalidate();
```

It does not help me. Please see my code below and prompt me solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/exercise_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/assign_circle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category2"
                android:text="test"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#C5CACF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/assign_circle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category1"
                android:text="test"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#C5CACF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/exercise_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout
            android:id="@+id/square_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/assign_circle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout
            android:id="@+id/square_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/assign_circle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category2"
                android:text="test1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#C5CACF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category1"
                android:text="test2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#C5CACF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In java code:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        SquareLayout layout1 = (SquareLayout) findViewById(R.id.square_1);
        SquareLayout layout2 = (SquareLayout) findViewById(R.id.square_2);
        TextView categoryTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category2);
        TextView categoryBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category1);

        int marginForTopCategory = dpFromPx(this, Integer.valueOf(layout2.getBottom() + categoryTop.getHeight() * 2).floatValue());
        int marginForBottomCategory = Float.valueOf(dpFromPx(this, Integer.valueOf(layout1.getBottom() - categoryBottom.getHeight() / 2))).intValue();

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)categoryTop.getLayoutParams();
        lp.topMargin = marginForTopCategory;
        categoryTop.setLayoutParams(lp);

        lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)categoryBottom.getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(0, marginForBottomCategory, 0, 0);
        categoryBottom.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    public static int dpFromPx(final Context context, final float px) {
        float result = px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round(result);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have runtime or compilation error? Please descride your problem

Comment: no runtime errors. Just wrong position of textViews. Maybe you can prompt, how can make circles like this, but with another methods and views.

Comment: @smail2133, please, check new java code, which was edited now

Comment: Саня thanks for the answer, but I found solution for my case. Only xml.

Answer (score 0):

I think main problem is that your first text view is behind the second rounded image.

Instead of mention in first linear layout mention in second layout. And make center gravity of that so that you can arrange it on second rounded image and it wont be overlap.

Comment: I can't because it's not image, it's shape.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@color/assign_exercise_circle_color"
        android:startColor="@color/assign_exercise_circle_color" />
</shape>

Comment: But you can add within second <com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout></com.ui.customviews.SquareLayout> and make second text view property gravity="center".. It should work